# Are wireless-chargers induction-stoves?

Tags: everyday-life, electromagnetic-induction

Since wireless chargers involve alternating magnetic fields, you would expect it to induce eddy currents on a metal surface.
According to a [survey by statista](https://www.statista.com/statistics/273432/metal-parts-of-a-billion-mobile-phones/), mobile phones are packed with a lot of metals as listed below.

1. Copper
2. Aluminum
3. ***Iron***
4. ***Nickel***
5. Tin
6. Silver
7. Gold

Most of these materials have good magnetic permeability and electric conductivity. **It is possible that a marginal magnetic flux from the charger would link with the phone components made up of these metals**.

***Wouldn't this make the metal components of a smart-phone susceptible towards over-heating during charging ?***

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wouldn't this make the metal components of a smart-phone susceptible
>   towards over-heating during charging?

It could. To reduce this effect, the magnetic field associated with wireless charging is commonly shielded.

There are two primary shielding methods: first is based on high pemeability materials, such as ferrite, and is used to redirect magnetic field, and second is based on high conductivity materials, such as copper, and is used to weaken magnetic field via eddy currents.

Below is a diagram of a typical shielding configuration, copied form [this site](http://cfe.com.tw/7-wpc/menu-wireless-power.htm):

[image]

Some data on the effectiveness of these shielding methods could be found [here](https://wirelesspowerconsortium.com/technology/shielding-effectiveness.html).